# Incorrect regular expression in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have a .sln file and i need to take some data from it. .sln file looks like [that](http://pastebin.com/h9VNEA95). I need names of projects from this file. Also I have a code which will work with taken string, if it looks correctly. So I tried to make a regular expression

> "Project(\"{[\w-]+}\")\s*=\s*\"(\w+)\"[,\s]+\"([\w\]*.vcxproj)\"[,\s]+\"({[\w-]+})\""

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifstr("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1.sln");
    string all;
    //Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "doctor", "dreryk\src\doctor\doctor.vcproj", "{5D031DBA-1903-4067-A2CE-01B104A08D48}"
    regex projParse("Project\(\"\{[\w-]+\}\"\)\s*=\s*\"(\w+)\"[,\s]+\"([\w\\]*\.vcxproj)\"[,\s]+\"(\{[\w-]+\})\"");
    ifstr.seekg(0);
    string pth, sol;
    match_results<string::const_iterator> what;
    while (getline(ifstr, sol))
    {
        string::const_iterator start = sol.begin();
        string::const_iterator end = sol.end();
        if (regex_search(start, end, what, projParse))
        {
            cout << what[0] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When i try this code, it says that there is a mistake. And I have no idea how to fix it.

error is :

> Unhandled exception at 0x775EC42D in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x0031E890.

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Escape the slashes in the regex string literal.

Comment: how can i escape them?

Comment: Just like you did in the file name

Comment: Or use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal): `std::regex e{R"(<expression here>)"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I gave this a go and I believe that I simplified your regex a bit.   Here's some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void show_matches(const std::string& in, const std::string& re)
{
    smatch m;
    regex_search(in, m, std::regex(re));
    if(m.empty()) {
        cout << "input=[" << in << "], regex=[" << re << "]: NO MATCH\n";
    } else {
        cout << "input=[" << in << "], regex=[" << re << "]: ";
        cout << "prefix=[" << m.prefix() << "] ";
        for(size_t n = 0; n < m.size(); ++n)
            cout << " m[" << n << "]=[" << m[n] << "] ";
        cout << "suffix=[" << m.suffix() << "]\n";
    }
}

int main()
{

    show_matches("Project(\"{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}\") = \"doctor\", \"dreryk\\src\\doctor\\doctor.vcproj\\\", \"{5D031DBA-1903-4067-A2CE-01B104A08D48}\"", 
    "Project\\(\"\\{([^\\}]*)\\W+(\\w+)\\W+(.*).vcproj\\W+([^\\}]*)\\W+");
}
```

And the regex:

```
Project\(\"\{([^\}]*)\W+(\w+)\W+(.*).vcproj\W+([^\}]*)\W+
```

Broken down:

```
Project\(\"\{  -- Literally match Project("{
([^\}]*) -- Capture group 1: Capture all characters until }
\W+ -- Eat all non-letter characters until the next capture group
\w+ -- Capture group 2 -- Eat everything until non character (in this case ")
\W+ -- Eat all non-letter characters until we get to our next capture group
(.*).vcproj  -- Capture group 3 eat everything until .vcproj
\W -- Eat everything until our last capture group
([^\}]*) -- Capture group 4 - eat everything until }
\W+ Eat until the end of the string.
```

Input:

```
Project(\"{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}\") = \"doctor\", \"dreryk\\src\\doctor\\doctor.vcproj\\\", \"{5D031DBA-1903-4067-A2CE-01B104A08D48}\""
```

Output:

```
prefix=[]  m[0]=[Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "doctor", "dreryk\src\doctor\doctor.vcproj\", "{5D031DBA-1903-4067-A2CE-01B104A08D48}"]  m[1]=[8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942]  m[2]=[doctor]  m[3]=[dreryk\src\doctor\doctor]  m[4]=[5D031DBA-1903-4067-A2CE-01B104A08D48] suffix=[]
```

The code above is great for testing regex in C++ if you ever need it -- it is derived from code on cppreference.com (credit where it's due)

Good luck

Comment: Did you try this code on your computer? Because I have some problems)

Comment: I made you a quick tester that will help you out:  Adding it to my answer now

Comment: @koshachok -- I'm going to be going to lunch for a while, if you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Yes, i need ur help, I tried your code, and i don't know why, but it doesn't work... I tried to change your expression, but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you see my most recent update to it?   I revamped it a lot, there's also a link to IDEOne where it's running / working without issues

Comment: oh, i sorry) i really didnt watch on your solution) Thank you)